# Uploading Laravel 5 Project to Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to deploy a Laravel 5 project to shared hosting from my localhost but I am facing so many problems. I have uploaded all files in a subfolder of my shared hosting (PHP 5.5) and when I try **http://domain.com/subfolder/public** its showing me 500 error. I check the `laravel.log` but found nothing, set the `storage/` to 777 but still no changed (showing last error from localhost).

I also check `.htaccess` and it seems good. I search a lot and try so many thing but still facing same problem.

Now, my shared hosting give access of SSH so I have installed a new Laravel project. Then copy my edited and added file except vendor from my localhost to Hosting. Then I update the composer and dump-autoload, Now my application is working file.

But I am not sure about the process I did. Is it the right way (I don't think so)? Please let me know what was the problem of directly uploaded file and is there any problem if I use second system for my production app.

Answer (score 1):

There are chances that your route cache is messed up. It is safe to `artisan route:clear`, `artisan cache:clear`, and `artisan view:clear` before uploading your files to ensure that no compiled script left - which usually tied to specific path.

But it is unclear, could you share your stacktrace for your error (and if possible share where your .htaccess file and it's content)?
sorry i can't comment, need higher point. However, by looking at your statement that it works by moving your files (controller, views, public, etc) but not the entire project, i believe clearing caches is the best to try.

As for the deployment of laravel project, there are methods suggested in [laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting). It is not a good idea to expose your entire laravel files in public folder. Nevertheless, there are many ways to deploy it.

Comment: try avoiding promotion or opinion based answers. otherwise this is a good answer

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late but you need to either:
1. Make laravel's public folder the root folder of your domain or
2. Make a sub-domain and point the root folder to your projects public folder. The disadvantage with this is that your sessions cannot be connected directly to your main domain's sessions.